# Improper border-bottom displayed for side-by-side divs

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
    <div style="width=50%;float:left">A paragraph with no margins specified
      <br>
      <br>A paragraph with a 2cm left margin.</div>
    <div style="width=50%;margin-left=51%">A paragraph with no margins specified.</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to display border at the bottom of the outer div, but the border is always displayed after the first inner div. Is the code wrong for border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the float to remain you can change the `overflow` property of the parent div to `auto`.

```html
  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; overflow:auto;">
    <div style="width=50%;float:left">A paragraph with no margins specified
      <br>
      <br>A paragraph with a 2cm left margin.</div>
    <div style="width=50%;margin-left=51%">A paragraph with no margins specified.</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left` from the top div. its the culprit